# How to make Facebook live video embed 16:9?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a trouble with embed live FB video because it's transforms 16:9 video to 1:1 format and make black lines at top and at the bottom. There is a video section on the users website that have 16:9 proportions. The user can change videos via CMS just pasting the iframe tag. So when the user add simple Facebook embed video it fit just perfect!... but when user is trying to add some LIVE video it just breaks everything because of square proportion. 
This is example how it shows live video on FB - 16:9, just like needed
[image: fb live example]

But then the embed iframe....
[image: fb live example]
Unfortunately the changing width and height of the embed IFRAME tag did not resolved the problem - it just cut the bottom of video.
So..any Ideas how to prevent Live FB video transforms to 1:1 and stay 16:9 like original??

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue but with just a basic Facebook video embed. Not sure if this is exactly related to the question but something in here might help get to the bottom of your issue.

My video was a 4:3 ratio and I wanted it to be responsive. I had to add attributes into the iframe as such, say width 400 and height 300 for a 4:3 video. Remember to specify the &height=300 in the video href.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fthortful%2Fvideos%2F1244848022205952%2F&show_text=0&width=400&height=300" width="400" height="300" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

The important thing to remember in your CSS is to ensure your padding-bottom matches your video ratio. In this case 75% as I have a 4:3 ratio.

Full code to make it responsive:

```
<div class="responsive-video">
   <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fthortful%2Fvideos%2F1244848022205952%2F&show_text=0&width=400&height=300" width="400" height="300" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>

.responsive-video {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 75%;
   height: 0;
}
.responsive-video iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```